# How to add a placeholder to a dropdown in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I need to add a placeholder into my `dropdown` and somehow it doesn't work.

Here is my input field:

```
<?= $form->field($category, 'id')->dropDownList($categoryList, [
    'id' => 'category-id',
    'prompt' => 'Select category', [
        'disabled' => true,
       ]
]); ?>
```

Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DropDownList` has no `placeholder`, use `'prompt'` instead:

```
$form->field($category, 'id')->dropDownList($categoryList, [
    'id' => 'category-id',
    'prompt'=>'- Select category -'
]);
```

Comment: Eh, got it. Tried to do so yesterday, but somehow `disabled = true` didn't worked too. Could you edit your code in which that `prompt` value would be disabled? Thank you

P.S. I've edited my code in the way I tried to disable the `prompt value`